# Как зарегистрировать класс конфигурации в web.xml?

Tags: java, spring-security, configuration, аннотации, web.xml

Есть приложение веб `Spring MVC`, я пытаюсь добавить туда авторизацию на `spring security`.

Изначально мой **web.xml** выглядел так:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>


    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

в пакете *com.rosteach.security* я создал класс конфигурации `Spring Security` :

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsServiceIMPL userDetailsService = new UserDetailsServiceIMPL();

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);//.passwordEncoder(getShaPasswordEncoder());
    }

    /*
    @Bean
    public ShaPasswordEncoder getShaPasswordEncoder(){
            return new ShaPasswordEncoder();
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/**").permitAll()
                //.antMatchers("/").access("ADMIN")

                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and();

        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .failureUrl("/error").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .permitAll();

        http.logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);
     }
}
```

И пытаюсь добавить эту конфигурацию в **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
 version="2.5">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- ADD FOR SPRING SEC -->
    <context-param>
         <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
         <param-value>
          org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
         </param-value>
    </context-param>

     <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com.rosteach.security.SecurityConfig</param-value>
  </context-param> 



    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>


        <!-- ADD FOR SPRING SEC -->
         <init-param>
          <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
          <param-value>
              org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
          </param-value>
         </init-param> 

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rosteach.security.SecurityConfig</param-value>
          </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

И после запуска получаю ошибку:

> WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found
>   for HTTP request with URI [ ... ] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'appServlet'

Как правильно добавить класс конфигурации Spring Security в web.xml?

Comment: Зачем вам bootstrap приложения через XML если одновременно с этим вы используете Java конфигурацию спринга? Выберите что-то одно. И, да, [вот документация](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-web-xml) по вашему вопросу.

Comment: Вам в web.xml ничего добавлять не нужно. Вам надо добавить класс инициализатор для SecurityConfig.java.